# object has no attribute 'actor_actions' (django-activity-stream)

Tags: django

I'm using `django-activity-stream` app and trying to [write custom stream](http://justquick.github.com/django-activity-stream/streams.html#writing-custom-streams).

accounts/managers.py

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from actstream.managers import ActionManager, stream
class MyActionManager(ActionManager):
    @stream
    def mystream(self, obj, verb='posted', time=None):
        if time is None:
            time = datetime.now()
        return obj.actor_actions.filter(verb = verb, timestamp__lte = time)
```

views.py

```
from actstream.models import Action
current_user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
current_user.actor_actions.mystream('commented')
```

settings.py

```
ACTSTREAM_MANAGER = 'accounts.managers.MyActionManager'
```

Error message > `'str' object has no attribute 'actor_actions'` and [full traceback](http://dpaste.org/ztHXE/)

thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

`django-activity-stream` has been broken lately for me with Django 1.4.
This is an error you share with someone on this [issue](https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream/issues/92). You should participate on that page so justquick can fix what looks like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem, could not figure out when this started happening. I updated to Django 1.4 some time ago and I just started seeing these problems.

What I eneded up doing is reverting the query

```
@stream
def my_stream(object, *args, **kwargs):
    ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(object.__class__)
    return self.model.objects.filter(actor_object_id=object.pk, 
        actor_content_type=ct, public=True, **kwargs)
```